# Form input in php being integer

Tags: php, integer

I currently have a form containing an input:

```
<input type="text" name="score" id="score" value="" />
```

Criteria: I need the value in this input to be below 40 and a positive integer or zero.

Having read up on `php.net` about `is_int()` and `is_numeric()`.  It advises using `is_numeric()` with form fields as these are always numeric strings.

I want to check if the value meets the above criteria but don't follow how I would do this in the above situation.

```
<?php
$score = $_POST['score'];
if(is_numeric($score) && $score <= 40){
    // Do good stuff
} else {
  // Don't do good stuff
} ?>
```

My issue with the above is that floats would pass this test and without using something  like `(int) $score` I can't use `is_int()` which then negates the `is_numeric` check.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why not check with `is_numeric` and then cast to `int`?

Comment: I don't want to change the input they gave so if they gave me 32.5 then I want to give that back it as the same value in the error

Comment: @timothystringer Then why do you need to validate if it's an integer more over whether it was a string,float,hex etc?

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665564/converting-text-to-int-from-a-form)

Comment: @DarylGill because it's a test result which only gets whole number scores so I need to make sure that's all I'm accepting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ctype_digit()](https://www.php.net/ctype_digit) to make sure the string consists only of numbers, and therefore is an integer - technically, this returns `true` also with very large numbers that are beyond int's scope. **Note** that this method will **not recognize negative numbers**.

Comment: Thanks this looks like it may be what I need

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$score = $_POST['score'];
if(ctype_digit($score) && $score <= 40){
    // Do good stuff
} else {
  // Don't do good stuff
} 
?>
```